# Type check for class methods by passing interface

Tags: typescript

Hey I have a class named Common with methods, some of the methods get optional param name possessionValue, the class get interface as prop.
There are Item class and PossessedItem class, the diffrent between them is that PossessedItem methods that includes optional param name possessionValue must be required.

My problem is when i send object with type **any** the param named possessionValue for PossessedItem instance isnt required.

I tought maybe to implement class middleware with proxy but it doesnt trigger on complie time.

My purpose in the example below is that possessedItem.a(example2); will trigger that possessionValue prop is required:

```
 class Common<AddionalParams = {}> {
    constructor() {
        const handler: any = {
            get: function (obj: { [x: string]: { apply: (arg0: any, arg1: any) => void; }; middleware: (arg0: any, arg1: any) => void; }, prop: string | number) {
                return typeof obj[prop] !== "function"
                    ? obj[prop]
                    : function (...args: any) {
                        obj.middleware(prop, args);
                        obj[prop].apply(obj, args);
                    };
            },
        };
        return new Proxy(this, handler);
    }

    middleware(prop: any, args: any[]) {
        const isIncludeNamedParam = args.find((param: any) => typeof param === "object")

        if (isIncludeNamedParam) {
            const isValid = 'possessionValue' in isIncludeNamedParam;

            if (!isValid) throw "possessionValue is required"
        }


    }

    a(args: { num1: any, possessionValue?: string } & AddionalParams): any {
        const { num1 } = args;
        return num1;
    }
}

type Possessed = {
    possessionValue: string
}

class Item extends Common { }
class PossessedItem extends Common<Possessed> { }


const item = new Item();
const possessedItem = new PossessedItem();

let example1 = { num1: 4 };
let example12: any = { num1: 4 };

// work
item.a(example1);
possessedItem.a(example1);

// not working
item.a(example12);
possessedItem.a(example12);
```